# How to write .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help with writing an .htaccess file.

What I want to do is to turn this...

`http://www.mysite.com/secure/b0dcfcddc93ef32fcf3ff642ecca043b/987987987/video.mp4`

into this ...

`http://www.mysite.com/secure.php?hash=b0dcfcddc93ef32fcf3ff642ecca043b&timestamp=987987987&file=video.mp4`

So what will go in .htaccess file and under which directory should I place it?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
RewriteRule ^secure/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)$ secure.php?hash=$1&timestamp=$2&file=$3 [NC,L]
```

The complete .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^secure/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)$ secure.php?hash=$1&timestamp=$2&file=$3 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The file should be placed in the webroot of your site.

Comment: Dot inside character class doesn't need to be escaped and hyphen needs to be escaped if not used at first or last position.

Answer (score 1):

nable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^secure/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+\.mp4)$ /secure.php?hash=$1&timestamp=$2&file=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```